# How to make Text widgets adaptive in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok so let's say I've got a Text object. How can I make it so that it gets an extra line (or height + 1) whenever I fill in the current line? like when it starts hiding the left of the line to show you the end?

**Edit**: since the question wasn't clear, I'll describe it more carefully.
Take this code as reference:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root, width=50, height=1)
text.pack
```

What it does, is creating a new Text widget of 1 line, and packs it. You may ask: Why don't you use the Entry widget? Because I want it to add more lines, instead of hiding what you already wrote to make some room for what you're writing, as shown below:

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

def adjustheight():
    while True:
        #check if whatever it's written takes more than a line to show
        if takesmorethan1line == True:  
            text.config(height=(text.cget("height") + 1)
            

 

root = Tk()

text = Text(root, width=50, height=1)
text.pack
Thread(target = adjustheight).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you wanting the actual height of the widget to grow?

Comment: With the default behavior wrap is supposed to be `tk.CHAR`. So lines should be broken if gets too long. You might've disabled it, otherwise it should be working fine by default.

Comment: Text widgets have an "height" parameter that is basically the number of lines the widget has. Let's say I have it set to 1. Now since it's difficult to explain get yourself this code and run it:
```python
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root, width = 50, height = 1)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```
then write a lot in it and you'll see by yourself. Instead of what that does I want it to modify the "height" parameter by adding 1, so that it can show more words.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question very well, But I assume that you have problem with wrapping a text. For instance when you reduce the window size, the text should break into multi lines. Here is as example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.my_label = tk.Label(
            self, text="Helllllooooooooooooooooooooooooo")

        self.my_label.bind('<Configure>',
                           lambda e: self.my_label.config(
                               wraplength=self.my_label.winfo_width()
                           ))

        self.my_label.pack()

        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Line breaking**, also known as **word wrapping**, is breaking a section of text into lines so that it will fit into the available width of a page, window or other display area, *[Read more.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap)*

### Solution

Tkinter's `Text` widget have this feature already built in. `wrap` is the option that will do it.

From the docs:

> This option controls the display of lines that are too wide.
> With the default behavior, wrap=tk.CHAR, any line that gets too long will be broken at any character.

Set `wrap=tk.WORD` and it will break the line after the last word that will fit.

### Example

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, wrap=tk.WORD)
text.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually I already looked into that, but it changes just how it breaks the line... I need the actual 'height' parameter to increase by 1 when it wraps